# Can a linear combination of primes equal their product?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there any set of different prime numbers $p_1$, $p_2$, ..., $p_n$ and integer numbers $k_1$, $k_2$, ..., $k_n$ (with $k_i>0$ $\forall i$ and $n>1$), for which the following holds?
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^n p_i = \sum_{i=1}^n k_ip_i
\end{equation}
I don't think there is any solution, but can't prove it.

Comment: May be restating your question will be a good idea: to find such $n$ when this is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many solutions, e.g.
$$
2\cdot 3\cdot 5=30=1\cdot2+1\cdot 3+5\cdot 5
$$
or
$$
2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7=210=2\cdot 2+5\cdot 3+6\cdot 5+ 23\cdot 7
$$